# Sorting answers in one question thread

Tags: support, answers, sorting

The answers are typically sorted in each thread: accepted answer followed by answers sorted by the earned points. But my account has changed this feature a few days ago and I don't know how. Now, the answers are sorted randomly, for example [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/) has 191 points in question and the answers are sorted by 215 (accepted), 0, 1 (deleted), -2 (deleted), 11, 7, 3 (deleted), 72. I want the normal sorting: 215, 72, 11, 7, 0, followed by three deleted answers.

It seems that it is an account-dependent problem but I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: side note: accepted answers are only kept on top if the author of the answer is not the OP themselves (as demonstrated by the powers that be in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338271/237989 )

Answer (score 4):

There are buttons at the top right corner of the answer area for sorting

- by latest active
- by votes
- by age (oldest first)

Perhaps you clicked one. If you don't see the buttons, try with a different browser. Click on "Votes" to revert to the original sorting by points (votes).